# how to encrypt through oauth2 authentication?

Tags: security, encryption, oauth-2.0, oauth

I want to know if there are a way to encrypt data with a key generate through the oauth2 authentication? I need to secure data for user on app that use only oauth2 login.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no such thing as OAuth 2.0 authentication. The Identity Layer built on top of OAuth 2.0 is called OpenID Connect so you may be referring to that. Secondly, securing data for a user inside an app is independent of the way of authenticating that user. You could dynamically generate a secret and encrypt the user data with that.

Comment: some data are in an external database that why I ask. so there are a way to did it with openid ?

Comment: He has a bit of confusion about what OAuth is for. Also, as said in the answer, OAuth is not an authentication protocol. I recommend you read first about OAuth and learn the basis